# Multiplicative effect in a simple linear regression model

Tags: regression, econometrics, linear

Consider a simple linear regression model $y=a+bx$ what does it mean to test if $x$ has a multiplicative effect on $y$, is this equivalent to test  $H_0: b>0$ versus $H_1 : b\le 0$ ? If this is true then how can this be conducted?

Comment: Where did you read about this? What was the context? It seems like a logarithmic specification where you can claim that, say, doubling $x$, triples $y$, but it is not totally clear what you intend to ask.

Comment: I received the solution and it is said that this means $H_0:b=0$ vs $H_1: b\not = 0$.

Comment: Well what do you want to test? The null and alternative hypotheses you’ve given in the comment are different from those in the original question.